# Using nested queries:SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, multivalue

I am trying to store the following data in a table where the visible_to is a multivalued attribute.

```
Wall_ID Facebook_ID Visible_To
W1      F1          F2,F3,F4
W2      F2          F1
W3      F3          F1
W4      F4          F1
```

I am trying to emulate Facebook on Oracle. I want to find the user who can view the max no of other's wall(here:F1).

I have gotten to the point of storing the multivalued attribute using NESTED table in Oracle 11g. Do I have to un-nest the table to find the result of the query or is there another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The only other solution I can think of is storing the Visible_to in a separate table with Wall_ID as foreign key.

Comment: This scenario would be much easier to implement with a NOSQL graph database. Especially if you have many connections to other data sets the performance will be much better, too.

Comment: Hi, this is for a simple DB with a max of ten records. Is there anyway to continue with the nested table method and answer the query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, then something like this should work (Please see the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f1ce/13)):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    f.wall_id
  , f.facebook_id
  , COUNT(t.COLUMN_VALUE) visible_to_count
  FROM facebook_data f
  CROSS JOIN TABLE(f.visible_to) t
  GROUP BY f.wall_id, f.facebook_id
  ORDER BY visible_to_count DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f1ce/13/0)**:

```
| WALL_ID | FACEBOOK_ID | VISIBLE_TO_COUNT |
--------------------------------------------
|      W1 |          F1 |                3 |
```

This simply unfolds the nested table and then aggregates so you can count up the number of values. You might also want to consider adding the `DISTINCT` keyword to the `COUNT()` function if you're likely to store duplicate values, or otherwise introduce cardinality in the query.